# Update TListView column headers programmatically?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, tlistview

Create a new VCL Forms Application and paste this `TListview` on its form:

```
object ListView1: TListView
  Left = 0
  Top = 80
  Width = 514
  Height = 150
  Align = alBottom
  Columns = <
    item
      Caption = 'Caption'
      Width = 100
    end
    item
      Caption = 'AColumn'
      Width = 100
    end
    item
      Caption = 'BColumn'
      Width = 100
    end>
  Items.ItemData = {
    055A0000000100000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF02000000FFFFFFFF000000
    00054900740065006D0031000A5300750062004900740065006D004F006E0065
    00603449440A5300750062004900740065006D00540077006F0048334944FFFF
    FFFF}
  TabOrder = 0
  ViewStyle = vsReport
  ExplicitLeft = 192
  ExplicitTop = 128
  ExplicitWidth = 250
end
```

Then put two buttons `Button1` and `Button2` on the form, so the form unit looks like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Column[2].AutoSize := True;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Width := ListView1.Width + 1;
end;

end.
```

Run the app. Click on `Button1` which sets the `AutoSize` property of the third column to `True`: This should extend the width of the third column until the ListView border. However, this change becomes visible only when you use these workarounds:

1. Extend the width of the form by dragging the form edge with the mouse, or:
2. Click the second button which does the same programmatically.

But how can I update the column headers programmatically, without using these workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` to the ListView:

```
var
  wpos: TWindowPos;
begin
  ListView1.Column[2].AutoSize := True;
  FillChar(wpos, Sizeof(wpos), 0);
  ListView1.Perform(WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, 0, @wpos);
end;
```

Comment: Uwe, thank you very much! Although I have looked at MSDN WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message, I don't understand exactly how it works in this context.

Comment: @user - Nothing to do with MSDN. You should look at the VCL code, there are only two calls for DoAutoSize of TCustomListview - from CreateWnd and from WMWindowPosChanged. So you should either recreate the api control or trigger a WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED - which is exactly what your button2 click handler does..